# Magento 2.4.5 Theme Assets to Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: magento2, aws, magento2.4.5, s3, magento2.4.5p1

I setup a Magento 2.4.5-p1 to save media folder to S3 Bucket. Everythin worked as expected with product images. After this I install a theme that includes a Frontend-Builder. This theme reads and writes some assets from/to media folder. When I try to open the theme settings in configuration returns me the error:

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Unable to create directory 'https://xxxxxxx-magento-files-xxxxxxx.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com'. Access forbidden.
```

When I inspect the media folder I see that is trying to create a folder and a new created folder named `https:` is there.
After this I checked the theme files and find the this:

```
public function getFileList()
    {
        $folderPath = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('/mgs/fbuilder/restore/');

        $io = $this->ioFile;
        $io->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
        $io->open(['path' => $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath($folderPath)]);
        try {
            return array_reverse($io->ls());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I think that the problem is that trying to get media folder path which in this case is the S3 bucket url instead of `var/www/...` which is the absolute path that must use.
Μaybe i'm completely wrong but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same magento version but the issue i am getting is that the updated css not syncing with amazon s3 bucket. This is when I update the theme color from backend. The css file is changed but its not syncing to s3 bucket even when remote-storage sync command is run. Do you know why the css file is not syncing?